# How to remove an element from ArrayList in Java and Assign it to a variable?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to remove elements from an ArrayList in Java and append it to another ArrayList. I am getting **boolean cannot be converted to int, x=arr.remove(arr.get(i));** error. Can someone help how to do it?

```
public class Solution 
{
    public static void func(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int m)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp= new ArrayList();
        int x;
        for(int i=arr.size();i<m;i--){
            x=arr.remove(arr.get(i));
            temp.add(x);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++){
        arr.add(temp.get(i));
        }
    }
    
}
```

I am getting error at line 8.

Comment: if it doesn't work in a single step, maybe it could works in 2 steps...

Comment: Please read the [List.remove(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) documentation. The return value is always boolean not the removed object.

Comment: Unrelated: `int i=arr.size()` should be `int i=arr.size()-1`

Comment: You want to use `arr.remove(i);` to invoke `remove(int)`. But the start must be at `arr.size() - 1` instead of `arr.size()`. Assuming you want to reverse the elements above `m`, the condition must be `i > m`. But you’re reinventing the wheel; you can do the entire operation with a single `Collections.reverse(arr.subList(m, arr.size()));` statement…